# Dotenv.config({path}) doesn't work despite I have precise the relevant path to my file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to import dotenv files inside a subirectory's files. I have include a path option inside the config specification to ensure the relevant file's importation.

Here my snippet.js:

```
const path=require("path")

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  console.log("in dotenv load, ",path.resolve(__dirname, "../"))
  require('dotenv').config({path: path.resolve(__dirname, "../")})
}
```

But the process.env relative to my .env return `undefined`. I nknow my `.env`'s file works well since I have tested it on another files on the root level.

Any hint would be great,
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to import multiple files in that directory. You can only `require` one `.env` file at a time. By default the dotenv package picks up the `.env` file in your current working directory using `path.resolve(process.cwd(), '.env')`.

Try specifying the name of the file like let's say `vars.env`

```
const path=require("path")

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  console.log("in dotenv load, ",path.resolve(__dirname, "../vars.env"))
  require('dotenv').config({path: path.resolve(__dirname, "../vars.env")})
}
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: effectively I had forget the `.env` at end of path, works well now

Comment: This worked for me...I was trying with path.join(__dirname, '../', `config/.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`);
But this was not working
Thanks for the answer